# Strange behavior of "node"

Tags: c, malloc

I am confused! Trying to create dynamic linked list and want to assign header by "malloc" function. From my code below compiler gives 2 error:

**in main:** [Error] `node' undeclared (first use in this function) and
**In function`newnode':** [Error] `node' undeclared (first use in this function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int a,b,c,d;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node * newnode(int, int, int, int);

int main(){
    struct node *header;
    header=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    int a,b,c,d;
    a=11;
    b=2;
    c=4;
    d=5;
    header->next=newnode(a,b,c,d);
    printf("\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

struct node * newnode(int aa, int bb, int cc, int dd)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->a =aa;
    temp->b =bb;
    temp->c =cc;
    temp->d =dd;
    temp->next=NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

I appreciate any advice! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no type `node`. You have type `struct node` and that's the one you need to pass to the `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as @icepack already noted, the type is named `struct node`, not `node`. So, `sizeof(node)` does not compile. You meticulously used `struct node` everywhere in your code except in those two spots with `sizeof`.

Secondly, consider using the

```
T *p = malloc(n * sizeof *p); /* to allocate an array of n elements */
```

idiom for memory allocation. E.g. in your case

```
temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

I.e. don't cast the result of `malloc` and prefer using `sizeof` with *expressions*, not with type names. Type names belong in declarations. The rest of the code should be as type-independent as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by previous answers, you have to use `struct node` when referencing to your structure.

However if you just want to use the declarative name node you can do as following:

```
typedef struct _node{
    int a,b,c,d;
    struct _node *next;
}  node;
```

Here you do not need to use `struct` before you reference a `node`

Edit: wrong syntax